Where is my disk located
On my server I have a 3.7TB disk (sdb) however I am unsure how to  navigate to it:
[21:51 svr11160 ~]# lsblk
NAME                                                                                            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb                                                                                               8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk
└─XSLocalEXT--d2903ea7--4fc7--307c--3dcf--c49f2653e24f-d2903ea7--4fc7--307c--3dcf--c49f2653e24f 253:0    0   3.7T  0 lvm  /run/sr-mount/d2903ea7-4fc7-307c-3dcf-c49f2653e24f
sr0                                                                                              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
sdc                                                                                               8:32   0   1.8G  0 disk
└─sdc1                                                                                            8:33   0   1.8G  0 part
sda                                                                                               8:0    0 136.1G  0 disk
├─sda2                                                                                            8:2    0    18G  0 part
├─sda5                                                                                            8:5    0     4G  0 part /var/log
├─sda3                                                                                            8:3    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda1                                                                                            8:1    0    18G  0 part /
└─sda6                                                                                            8:6    0     1G  0 part [SWAP]
[21:51 svr11160 ~]#

I wish to share it using NFS however am not sure what path to use in the exports file.

By the looks of the naming convention that disk  might be used for a Storage Repository by XenServer https://support.citrix.com/s/article/CTX121896-how-to-introduce-a-local-storage-repository-in-xenserver?language=en_US and should then be managed from there.

It is however I wanted to copy a disk image directly using sftp from a Windows machine.
